# Why doesn't the voltage across this diode follow the voltage from the power supply?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Why the voltage across the Load resistor $R_L$ remains constant at 0.7 volts as long as the diode is forward biased?

Both diode and load resistor are parallel so the voltage across them should be equal but why 0.7 volts always? Shouldn't the out put voltage change as the source voltage change across the diode and resistor?

This Pic is a camera Pic from my book.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A diode is a nonlinear device whose current-vs-voltage curve is exponential.  The exponential is extremely steep — so steep, in fact, that it's frequently useful to model it as a step function. In this step function approximation, a diode draws zero current if the applied voltage is less than its "turn on" threshold. But above the turn-on threshold, the diode (in this approximation) becomes a conductor, drawing as much current as your power supply will provide, while clamping the voltage drop at the turn-on voltage.

The parallel resistor in your diagram is just along for the ride.

Comment: You mean that once the voltage across the parallel set of diode and resistor reach 0.7 volts then diode becomes a conductor and after that when the voltage from the source rises then all current will go through the diode and no current will go to the resistor?

Comment: No. I mean that the diode draws as much current as necessary so that the voltage drop across the diode doesn't exceed the turn-on voltage. "Conductor," as you have observed, isn't quite the correct word. The better word is "diode" — but that's the subject of your question.

Comment: How current draws current as much as necessary to keep the voltage across it at 0.7 volt?

Comment: Howcome the diode is synchronized with the source voltage this way?

Comment: The "step function" is an approximation to a [very steep exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth). A handwaving explanation is that the conductivity of the [p-n junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P–n_junction) in the diode depends on the current through the diode. When the voltage across the junction is small, there are only a few charge carriers, which don't feel much force from the electric field. When the voltage increases, the force on the charge carriers increases, but the number of charge carriers also increases. Very different from a linear (ohmic) resistor.

Comment: So once the voltage across the diode and load resistance becomes 0.7 volts the diode is forward biased. Suppose source voltage was 0.79 at that moment. What will happen next when the voltage of the source will increase to 0.8 then? Please explain how the diode will maintain 0.7 volt across it which was for the 0.79 volts from the source but now the source voltage increases to 0.8 volts.

Comment: If you set the voltage supply to 0.5V (direct current), the voltage will be [divided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) across $R_1$ and $R_L$, with no current through the diode. If you set the voltage source to 10V, you'll have 0.7V across the diode and across $R_L$, and you'll have the remaining 9.3V across $R_1$.  The current from the power supply will be $I_\text{total} = 9.3\mathrm V/R_1$; the current through $R_L$ will be $I_L = 0.7\mathrm V/R_L$; the rest of the current flows through the diode. (All this assumes the step-function conductivity approximation.)

Comment: Got it man. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The voltage vs current characteristics of a real diode (cyan), an ideal diode (red) and an idealised diode (blue) are shown below.

[image]

Note that once the voltage across a real diode is above about $0.7\,\rm mV$ a small change in the voltage produces a very large change in the current, ie the diode acts like a short circuit.

The red characteristic for a real diode shows the diode to be a perfect conductor when the voltage across it is greater that $0\,\rm V$.

The blue characteristic (idealized) is a reasonable approximation to a real diode.

With the circuit shown in your diagram with a $5\,\rm V$ peak sinusoidal input and $1\,\rm k\Omega$ resistors the outputs when using the three types of diode are shown below.

[image]

With the real diode you will note that the maximum voltage when the sine wave is clipped is around $0.7\,\rm V$ and the idealised diode, which consists of an ideal diode in series with a $0.7\,\rm V$ supply, gives a reasonable approximation to the output from a real diode.

The graphs were produced using the [Spinning Numbers sandbox](https://spinningnumbers.org/circuit-sandbox/index.html?value=%5B%5B%22v%22%2C%5B88%2C80%2C0%5D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22sin(0%2C5%2C1%2C0%2C0)%22%2C%22_json_%22%3A0%7D%2C%5B%223%22%2C%220%22%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B88%2C80%2C88%2C48%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B88%2C128%2C88%2C160%5D%5D%2C%5B%22s%22%2C%5B264%2C48%2C0%5D%2C%7B%22color%22%3A%22cyan%22%2C%22offset%22%3A%220%22%2C%22_json_%22%3A3%7D%2C%5B%222%22%5D%5D%2C%5B%22g%22%2C%5B144%2C160%2C0%5D%2C%7B%22_json_%22%3A4%7D%2C%5B%220%22%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B88%2C160%2C144%2C160%5D%5D%2C%5B%22d%22%2C%5B200%2C104%2C0%5D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22area%22%3A%221%22%2C%22is%22%3A%221.0e-14%22%2C%22Vt%22%3A%220.026%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22ideal%22%2C%22_json_%22%3A6%7D%2C%5B%221%22%2C%220%22%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B264%2C48%2C264%2C72%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B264%2C120%2C264%2C160%5D%5D%2C%5B%22r%22%2C%5B176%2C48%2C1%5D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22R1%22%2C%22r%22%3A%221k%22%2C%22_json_%22%3A9%7D%2C%5B%222%22%2C%223%22%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B88%2C48%2C128%2C48%5D%5D%2C%5B%22r%22%2C%5B264%2C72%2C0%5D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22R2%22%2C%22r%22%3A%221k%22%2C%22_json_%22%3A11%7D%2C%5B%222%22%2C%220%22%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B200%2C152%2C200%2C160%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B144%2C160%2C200%2C160%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B264%2C160%2C200%2C160%5D%5D%2C%5B%22v%22%2C%5B200%2C56%2C0%5D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22dc(0.7)%22%2C%22_json_%22%3A15%7D%2C%5B%222%22%2C%221%22%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B200%2C56%2C200%2C48%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B176%2C48%2C200%2C48%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B264%2C48%2C200%2C48%5D%5D%2C%5B%22view%22%2C0%2C0%2C2%2C%2250%22%2C%2210%22%2C%221G%22%2Cnull%2C%22100%22%2C%222%22%2C%221000%22%5D%5D) by clicking on the $\fbox{TRAN}$ button.

Comment: So once the voltage across the diode and load resistance becomes 0.7 volts the diode is forward biased. Suppose source voltage was 0.79 at that moment. What will happen next when the voltage of the source will increase to 0.8 then? Please explain how the diode will maintain 0.7 volt across it which was for the 0.79 volts from the source but now the source voltage increases to 0.8 volts.

Comment: Are you asking about a real diode and the circuit I used in the simulation which contains a potential divider type network?

Comment: I am.asking about the ideal diode in the diagram in my question.

Comment: If the input voltage is high the voltage across the diode is kept at $0.7\,\rm V$ by the diode allowing more current to pass through it so that the potential drop across resistor $R_1$ increase. Thus you have, voltage of supply (increases) = voltage across resistor $R_1$ (increases) + voltage drop across the diode (stays the same at $0.7\,\rm V$.

Comment: Are you on facebook or insta? I saw many answers from you. Really I want to stay incontact from you.

Answer (score 2):

The book makes a simplification. The voltage on the diode will change logarithmically with the current that is flowing through it. For practical diode circuits that means it will change between maybe 0.4V at the low end and 1V at the upper end with 0.7V being "typical" for a silicon diode. In practice one would have to be more careful about it than the simplified treatment suggests. For power supply circuits rectifier voltage drop changes quite a bit about the efficiency and the heat that needs to be removed from the circuit to assure reliability. For applications as a voltage reference one would have to control the current through the diode carefully (e.g. with a current source), otherwise the precision would be seriously lacking. There is the additional temperature dependence, which makes these simple diode circuits often enough useless for analog electronics.